# Privacy compliant Facebook Like button with count

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph, privacy, facebook-likebox

*Here in Germany privacy rules (Datenschutz) are really strict. Chances are high to get a cease and desist letter (Abmahnung) from a competitor when I put the regular facebook like button on my webpage. Since the facebook like button tracks the individual visitor, even when he doesn't use the Like Button.*

["Two click solutions"](http://thepoliticsofsystems.net/2011/09/a-two-click-like-button-for-more-privacy/) got invented to overcome that situation.

[image]

However, they don't show the like count of the URL to be liked when disabled. (See screenshot: "21" only shows up in activated state) I know that [it is possible to retrieve this like count through open graph api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020720/facebook-like-button-can-it-be-made-read-only).

Is there already a solution that features a "two click like button" including count in disabled state? Maybe a wordpress plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Following plugin does the job. However its still beta and it comes without any icons (because of trademark issues) So, only powerusers will recognize it as facebook like button.

[image]

http://www.selbstaendig-im-netz.de/2013/02/14/social-web/sin-socialshare-plugin-3-betaversion/ (only German, there is a download of the plugin zip file)

The plugin is not yet in wordpress org plugindirectory